# Detect SSL/TLS during SqlConnection

Tags: .net, .net-4.5, azure-sql-database, wireshark, sqlconnection

I am trying to determine that an `SqlConnection` with .NET 4.5 is using TLS to connect. So, I have determined the IP address of my database and am listening with WireShark. It looks like the connection does not use either SSL or TLS. What am I missing?

## Connection String

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.DataSource = "tcp:some_server.database.windows.net,1433";
builder.InitialCatalog = "some_db";
builder.UserID = "some_user_id";
builder.Password = "some_password";
builder.Encrypt = true;
builder.TrustServerCertificate = false;
builder.ConnectTimeout = 30;
```

## Wireshark Output

[image: Wireshark Output]

## Research

[Windows Azure SQL Database Connection Encryption](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2763.windows-azure-sql-database-connection-encryption.aspx) says that data transfer uses tabular data streams (TDS in Wireshark) over a secure sockets layer and that SQL Azure does not support unencrypted connections.

Comment: pre-login establishes what connection protocol to use so look at the rows after pre-login. SQL Azure does not support UNencrypted connections (your research statement has a typo) so it will actually terminate if pre-login is unable to agree on a supported encryption protocol (I think 1.1 is the lowest).  Also, although it's generally immaterial when you have encrypt=true (cert validation will occur), as a matter of good habit/practice, trust server cert=false should be default and only value to use.